# Open google maps from hyperlink

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to design a webpage specially for android users so i was wondering if there is a hyper link format that can open up google maps just like the call function eg

```
<a href="tel:0766551121"> Call me now </a>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If by "open up Google Maps" you mean the native Android Google Maps application instead of opening the link in the Android's browser then according to [Geo Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) you can use the following [Geo URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI) formats that trigger intents that will open the Google Maps application on the device to the given location or query:

- geo:latitude,longitude
- geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
- geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
- geo:0,0?q=business+near+city

For Google Streetview you can use:

- google.streetview:cbll=lat,lng&cbp=1,yaw,,pitch,zoom&mz=mapZoom

For details on the available options see [the official Google Maps Intents documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

Comment: I sent myself a mail with the first format but doesn't work. It tries to open it with browsers instead.

Comment: By far the best comment i found on the net about this topic, thanks sir !

Comment: it is also possible to open maps as navigation with walk mode? so user do not have to click on "get directions"

Comment: @miro Yes, you have to append the "&mode=w" parameter, For more information see [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) . I've also updated the response to include the official docs links for the Google Maps intents.

Comment: Can I also put a pin in the map in this way?

Answer (score 13):

use [GEO URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI) for open a map on  hyper link click  like:

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">open map</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am going with @Mnemonic Flow

- geo:latitude,longitude
- geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
- geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
- geo:0,0?q=business+near+city

Create your Uri

**Example**

**Step 1 :** Create link like

```
Uri uri;
```

- geo:latitude,longitude

  `uri = Uri.parse("geo:47.6,-122.3")`
- geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom

  `uri = Uri.parse("geo:47.6,-122.3?z=11")`
- geo:0,0?q=my+street+address

  `uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0q=The+Eldorado+Park,+Rampar+Mota,+Gujarat,+India")`
- geo:0,0?q=business+near+city

  `uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0q=The+Eldorado+Park,+Rampar+Mota,+Gujarat,+India")`

**Step 1** Create method like below

```
public void showMap(Uri geoLocation) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(geoLocation);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And Call like this

```
showMap(uri);
```

**Step 2 :** Add intent-filter in you manifiest file

```
<activity YourActivity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="geo" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```