# Location link sent via SMS is working in Android browser but not on iPhone browser

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-chrome, sms

I'm developing an Android App that can send the user's current location via SMS.

For sending the SMS I use the following code:

```
String phoneNumber = "123456" //example
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            StringBuilder smsBody = new StringBuilder();
            smsBody.append("This is my location:\n");
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/?q=loc:" + location.getLatitude()
                + "+" + location.getLongitude();
            smsBody.append(uri);
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody.toString(),
                    null, null);
```

Now, when I send this to an Android device, I get a SMS with the link, and it opens perfectly in the native browser and in Google Chrome.

But, if I send it to an iPhone device - using the native browser (Safari) - it gives me an error that it cannot open the address because it is incorrect, but if I open it using Chrome (also on iPhone) - It works perfectly.

Has anyone got a clue why this is happening? Any workaround?

Here is an exact copy of the SMS message that is received:

*This is my location:
[http://maps.google.com/?q=loc:32.05688742112759+34.899831548802496](http://maps.google.com/?q=loc:32.05688742112759%2034.899831548802496)*

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is a screen capture of the error I'm getting when I try to open the link on an iPhone 4 running iOS7
[image]

Comment: have you tried using `https` instead of `http` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because iOS support its native map. Your query url only works with google map.
You can try this url for iOS:
    "http://maps.apple.com/?q=loc:32.05688742112759+34.899831548802496"

Comment: Well, Seeing it opens in a browser, it should support it, and apparently iPhone 5 does support it (see answer below). Do you have any source or link to support your answer? Thanks!

Comment: you can check here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: Well, it said there that you CAN use that link form, not a MUST. But, based on your answer, I also found this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223533/how-to-launch-google-maps-on-iphone-via-web-link).


When I used the link the way you said it DID work both on Android and iOS. 


Thanks for you help solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

IOS don't support SMS location by link

Comment: Can you provide an official or creditable link to this fact? Many thanks

Comment: hm it's an ordinary http - it should open in Safari