# Call to GPS app via html

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, gps, smartphone

I am developping a website intended to mobile phones and I've got a contact section with a mailto: tel: for the mail and telephone, is there any similar function that would make a call to the default gps app of the phone and preload it with GPS coordinates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For android:**

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">open map</a>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204612/open-google-maps-from-hyperlink) & [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI) for details.

**For iphone:**

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino">Cupertino</a>
```

If you want to use coordinates instead of location name, see [here for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

(Found them on net, not tested.)

Comment: Thany you, I used them + links to here maps and bing maps for Nokias & Windows phones :)