# Maps in Cordova 3.5.0 (Multi-Platform)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, maps

I'm making an application that needs map links opening in default maps application... Can anybody help me. This is my current problematic code.

```
<a href="maps:q=Location" onClick="window.open('geo:0,0?q=Location', '_system');">
```

This creates errors in Android when I return to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=Place','_system','location=no');" href="geo:0,0?q=Place">Directions to Place</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=21.551464, 73.951399"> 
   Open Maps
 </a>
```

Reference :
[Open google maps from hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204612/open-google-maps-from-hyperlink)

Hope this may help you

Comment: Sorry but this just opens google maps in a browser in both android and ios.