# how to send location coordinates from an app to any map app?

Tags: android

I have tried sending to google map but I want my app to ask in which app you want to open or just shows the option of my phone map apps, like it does in case we click on some URL, it shows all the browser in our phone and let us select.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this question - you are probably going want to use `geo:latitude, longitude` links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204612/open-google-maps-from-hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:" + model.getLocation_lat() + "," + model.getLocation_lng());

// you can use this if you have other information like address of place
    Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:" + model.getLocation_lat() + "," + model.getLocation_lng()+ "?q=" + model.getAddress());    

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoLocation);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose an application "));
```

That is all thing you need.

Answer (score 0):

Good question: You can send a Intent with ACTION_VIEW where the meta data is a string starting with the schema geo:

It is described here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#ViewMap

And it is simply:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:47.6,-122.3?z=11");
startActivity(intent);
```

Theres more options sending more arguments in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you two options open in browser or google map

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q="+your address);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
                {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```